# Reading free-busy calDAV iCloud PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, icloud, caldav

I'm trying to read free-busy information from an iCloud calendar.

I based my solution on this php client https://github.com/muhlba91/icloud/blob/master/PHP/icloud.php

**What works so far:**
Getting the Apple user number from an apple ID, using the credentials, this is needed to access the calDAV URL

Getting a list of the available calendars from a user (eg. Home, Work, ...)

**What's not working:**
I cannot get a valid response from the Apple calDAV server.

The request (EDITED):

```
$ctag_request="<A:propfind xmlns:A='DAV:' xmlns:cs='https://p01-caldav.icloud.com/**USERID**/calendars/home/'>
    <A:prop>
       <cs:getctag />
    </A:prop>
</A:propfind>";


    $response=simplexml_load_string($this->doPropfindRequest($user['appleID'], $user['applepass'], $url, $ctag_request));
```

This is the DoRequest function. This is exactly the same as the propfind function i'm using to get the userID & list of calendars, except for the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST which is set to PROPFIND or REPORT.
I conclude that the cURL part of my solution is correctly built.

```
function doReportRequest($user, $pw, $url, $xml)
{
    //Init cURL
    $c=curl_init($url);
    //Set headers
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Depth: 1", "Content-Type: text/xml; charset='UTF-8'", "User-Agent: DAVKit/4.0.1 (730); CalendarStore/4.0.1 (973); iCal/4.0.1 (1374); Mac OS X/10.6.2 (10C540)"));
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //Set SSL
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    //Set HTTP Auth
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$pw);
    //Set request and XML
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PROPFIND');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //Execute
    $data=curl_exec($c);
    //Close cURL
    curl_close($c);

    return $data;
}
```

However, what apple returns me on this request is the following:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#259 (1) {
  ["response"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#261 (2) {
    ["href"]=>
     string(27) "/8126574070/calendars/home/"
     ["propstat"]=>
     object(SimpleXMLElement)#262 (2) {
      ["prop"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#260 (1) {
        ["getctag"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#263 (0) {
        }
      }
      ["status"]=>
      string(22) "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
    }
  }
}
```

I get a 404 response. I think the problem is that the url is wrong. However i can't find anywhere online what the correct apple caldav URL is.

I'm hoping there is some calDAV expert that can help me on this issue.

**EDIT**

Allright, i edited the code/question since free-busy isn't supported by Apple and it's semi working.

Answer (score 1):

The supported-report precondition on the REPORT method is documented over here: http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc3253.html#rfc.iref.d.17

It simply means that this iCloud calendar does not support freebusy queries. You can see the same in the OS X calendar app if you create an event and open the availability panel.
It says 'this calendar does not support availability' ...

To extend the answer to the edited question: This is wrong:

```
$ctag_request="<A:propfind xmlns:A='DAV:' xmlns:cs='https://p01-caldav.icloud.com/**USERID**/calendars/home/'>
  <A:prop>
    <cs:getctag />
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>";
```

The namespace of the [getctag](https://trac.calendarserver.org/browser/CalendarServer/trunk/doc/Extensions/caldav-ctag.txt?order=name) property is "http://calendarserver.org/ns/". Try this:

```
$ctag_request="<propfind xmlns='DAV:'>
  <prop>
    <getctag xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/' />
  </prop>
</propfind>";
```

The https://p01-caldav.icloud.com/**USERID**/calendars/home/ is the URL of a calendar collection. It is not an XML namespace.

And yes, if you get a 404, your URL is wrong / doesn't exist.

Another issue might be that your authentication credentials are wrong. Are you providing an [application password](https://support.busymac.com/help/44585-connecting-to-icloud-with-an-app-specific-password) in your basic auth?

Comment: If i try doing a calendar-query i get the same supported-report. Does this mean that iCloud also does not support calendar-queries? If so, how am i supposed to read event information via calDAV ?

Comment: AFAIK iCloud supports a subset of calendar-query. Ie it does support time-range queries as used by iOS. But I kinda suspect that something is wrong with your request. Maybe add the HTTP representation of your issue to your question.